# $|G|=8$, then $G$ has proper nontrivial subgroups of order $4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and $|G|=8$, then $G$ has proper nontrivial subgroups of order $4$. I can't see why. Does it follow by Sylow Theorem?

Comment: Depends how exactly you state Sylow theorems... some variants include existence of any prime power size dividing the order

Comment: @Wojowu Can it be proved more easily without Sylow?

Comment: Hint for a direct proof: consider the center of $G$. You might want to consider the abelian case separately.

Comment: @Eric Have a look at the duplicate for a proof without Sylow.